# Event handling with JavaScript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I am attempting to create a tic-tac-toe browser game utilizing JavaScript and jQuery, along possibly with PHP.

I have the board arranged how I like utilizing a table and adding borders appropriately. Each cell in the tic-tac-toe board has its own unique id, e.g topleft, topright, botleft, etc.

For testing purposes, before I can even get to writing the code supporting the game, I am attempting to get an "X" to appear when the user clicks an appropriate spot, however I am having no luck.

Here is the JavaScript I have so far:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

                function mark()
                {
                        document.getElementById('topleft').innerHTML = "X";
                }

                function init()
                {
                        var button = document.getElementById('topleft');
                        button.addEventListener('click', mark, false);
                }

                $(document).ready(function()
                {
                        $('#topleft').click(function()
                        {
                        });

                });
        </script>
```

And here is the html:

```
<body>
        <div>
                <table>
                        <tr>
                                <td id="upleft">
                                </td>
                                <td id="upcenter">
                                </td>
                                <td id="upright">
                                </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
```

By my logic, the page loads, and then topleft gets a click listener. Upon clicking that cell the listener is tripped, which then calls the function mark to place an X in the cell, however nothing appears clickable on the page, and no mark appears afterwards.

If anyone can spot an error or has a suggestion I'd be grateful!

Additionally, if you have any ideas for programming the logic behind a tic-tac-toe board (nothing too fancy) I'd be grateful as well.

Comment: Your code is whack, check out some jQuery tutorials first!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it this way:

```
$('#topleft').click(function() {
    $(this).text('X');
});
```

Next step, don't use `#topleft` directly, but generic case className (`$('.tictactoe-case')`) to not repeat yourself.

Good luck!